# How does TensorFlow calculate FLOPS?

Tags: tensorflow

I wanted to implement something similar in Caffe for myself but I'm clueless how this is done.
How exactly is `TensorFlow` calculating such Statistics ?

Comment: Are you referring to contrib.tfprof?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: Actually I read this tutorial : https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/ and I remmember somewhere I saw even more , unfortunetaly I can not find it, I dont know if its related to contrib.tfprof .